# How to change file permissions recursively on Midnight Commander?

Tags: mc

If I select all the files and use `ctrl + x c` it just asks me to change permissions to all the selected files individually and if I do it at the directory level all of the files inside are unaffected. Is there a way to change the permissions of all the selected files at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I had opened this question but a little while after asking it I found that I just need to use  in the chmod window (ctrl-x c) instead of , that would produce the results I wanted.

Comment: Set, Set All and Set Marked do different things but neither run recursively AFAIK.

Comment: So that is good to know, that makes mc chown and chmod totally useless, as I always do these recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Chmod, Chown and Advanced Chown don't work recursively. Use External Panelize command to list all your files in a panel, select some or all files and execute Chmod.

Comment: I forgot I had opened this question but a little while after asking it I found that I described can be done. I just need to use <set all> in the chmod window (ctrl-x c) instead of <set> which would just run chmod on a single file.